# Create a simple loop to apply a model by colums in R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, regression, predict

I have a database containing the presence (1) or absence (0) of cells in different growth stages (*enlarging*, *thickening* and *maturing*) for different trees during many years. I collected data every certain days of the year (DOY; January 1 would be DOY 1, January 2 would be DOY 2, etc.). The column DOY2 is just another column with those same DOY, but squared. Here's a simple reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame("Year" = c(2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012,
                            2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013,
                            2013, 2013),
                 "Tree" = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 41, 41,
                            41, 41, 41),
                 "DOY" = c(65, 97, 125, 177, 214, 65, 97, 125, 177, 214,
                           61, 99, 118, 166, 221),
                 "DOY2" = c(4225, 9409, 15625, 31329, 45796, 4225, 9409, 15625,
                            31329, 45796, 3721, 9801, 13924, 27556, 48841),
                 "Enlarging" = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0),
                 "Thickening" = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
                 "Maturing" = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0))

 print(df)
   Year Tree DOY  DOY2 Enlarging Thickening Maturing
1  2012   15  65  4225         0          0        0
2  2012   15  97  9409         0          0        0
3  2012   15 125 15625         1          1        1
4  2012   15 177 31329         0          1        1
5  2012   15 214 45796         0          0        0
6  2012   22  65  4225         0          0        0
7  2012   22  97  9409         1          0        0
8  2012   22 125 15625         1          1        1
9  2012   22 177 31329         1          1        1
10 2012   22 214 45796         0          0        0
11 2013   41  61  3721         0          0        0
12 2013   41  99  9801         1          0        1
13 2013   41 118 13924         1          1        1
14 2013   41 166 27556         1          1        1
15 2013   41 221 48841         0          0        0
```

I want to apply a logistic regression using the `glm` function with a quadratic adjustment for the *enlarging* and *thickening* stage, and a non-quadratic logistic regression for the *mature* stage. As I have understood, for the quadratic adjustment I would need to square the DOY, that's why I have the column DOY2. I was thinking about something similar to this:

```
Enlarging.glm <- glm(Enlarging ~ DOY + DOY2,  family = "binomial", data = df)
Thickening.glm <- glm(Thickening ~ DOY + DOY2,  family = "binomial", data = df)
Maturing.glm <- glm(Maturing ~ DOY,  family = "binomial", data = df)
```

Now this is important: I need to obtain **daily predictions** for the regression, from day 1 to day 365 of the year. As I need daily predictions for this model for every growth stage, I guess I should create a new dataframe containing every DOY and every DOY squared (DOY2). I'm not very sure about the syntax here, maybe something like `new_DOY`. Not sure either if I should use the `predict`  or `predict.glm`  function, but:

```
new_DOY = data.frame(DOY = seq(1, 365, 1), DOY2 = seq(1, 365, 1)^2) 

Enlarging.output <- as.vector(predict(Enlarging.glm, new_DOY, type = "response"))
Thickening.output <- as.vector(predict(Thickening.glm, new_DOY, type = "response"))
Maturing.output <- as.vector(predict(Maturing.glm, new_DOY, type = "response"))
```

The thing here is that I want to apply those models and predictions for every tree of every year from my database. I have like 6 trees per year, 10 years, so 60 times I should run all this code for every different tree. Instead, and to be more efficient, I was wondering how to write a simple loop to apply the models and predictions for every tree, every year, but I have no idea about how the loop syntax works and I'm completely stuck here. I hope someone can give me some light, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, i think you can achieve what you want without the need for loops. Performing the same operation over multiple levels of a variable (or multiple variables) is possible with `dplyr`'s `group_by()`. For example, take a look at the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(marginaleffects)

df %>% 
    group_by(Year, Tree) %>% 
    glm(Enlarging ~ DOY + I(DOY^2),  family = "binomial", data = .) %>% 
    marginaleffects::predictions()
```

Note two things:

1. You do not need to create `DOY2` as a separate column, but can introduce the square of `DOY` directly within the model by using the syntax `I(DOY^2)`
2. Using the `predictions()` function from the `marginaleffects` package (run `install.packages("marginaleffects")` if you don't already have it installed), you can estimate the predictions for each day within your data.

**Edit in response to question in comments:**

By default, `marginaleffects::predictions()` only returns the variables used in the model. You can return everything by supplying a data frame explicitly to the `newdata` argument:

```r
fit <- function(x) {
    mod <- glm(Enlarging ~ DOY + I(DOY^2),  family = "binomial", data = x)
    marginaleffects::predictions(mod, newdata = x)
}
df %>% group_by(Year, Tree) %>% fit(.)
```

Note that the output is a standard data frame with a fancy `print()` function. This means that while not all columns are printed, everything can be accessed using all normal tools like `df$Tree`.

Comment: Hello @C.Robin , thanks a lot for your answer. I tried this method despite being so little code (it was surprising) and I got a new dataframe with estimates in which I have lost the 'Tree' and 'Year' columns, so I don't really know which estimates are from which tree or year. Besides, it doesn't seem to have calculated daily estimates, but just estimates for the previous DOY's that I had in my initial database. Do you know why could this be happening? I would be terribly interested in using this method since seems SO easy to code. Thank you again.

Comment: I added some extra information to the post to answer this question.